# How to add min to redux form field

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

How can I add a *min* value to the form field in Redux form so that the value won't go below a certain value (In my case 0)?

I've tried adding *min* attribute to the Field element but that doesn't seem to work.

```
  <Field name="cost" className="placeholder-no-fix form-control" component="input" min="0" type="number" placeholder="cost" />
```

Also, I've added validation for the field as

```
const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}
  if(values.cost < 0){
    errors.cost = 'Negetive Value'
  }
  return errors
}
```

The validation is working perfectly but I don't want the input to go below 0 on *decrease value* button press

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux Form `Field` does not have `min` props. If you want `min` value you have to customize `input` component you pass to `Field`. Something like:

```
<Field name="cost" className="placeholder-no-fix form-control" component={CustomInputComponent} type="number" placeholder="cost" />
 
 const CustomInputComponent = ({
   field,
   form: { touched, errors }, 
   ...props
 }) => (
   <div>
     <input type="number" min="0" {...field} {...props} /> //<-- set min value here
   </div>
 );
```

Comment: Happy to ear that. Have a nice coding =)

Answer (score 1):

change Your input Value by force to 0 when user Entered Negative Value

```
if(values.cost < 0){
    errors.cost = 'Negative Value';
    values.cost = 0;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Loved this short-handed way of doing it.